# Noisy fan at Dell 5547

Tags: laptop, gpu, fan

Please take a look at screenshot with information about the hardware at Pastebin or on screenshot:

- http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=WGEQCCet

[image]

Note the section "Temperature" AMD Radeon. Perhaps this is causing the problem.
Please, tell me what can be caused by a noisy fan.

Comment: GPU core 511˚C ?!? That would have melted by now. Solder flows at about 200˚C, so if you still have graphics & no smoke, the reporting is wrong, but the fans are therefore being told to spin as fast as possible to cool it from that fictitious temperature.

Comment: Solved the problem: In device Manager, disable AMD Radeon, then rebooted and turned on again.

Comment: I tried disabling AMD RADEON, and enabling back again, didn't work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value can't bo correct.

When the air comming out of the fan is warm, then the problem isn't the fan.

Otherwise take the `servicetag number` (its on the bottom of the notebook or behind the battery) and type in in there: www.dell.com/servicetag. You can download then the newest drivers / firmware for exactly your notebook.

I remember dell notebook issues with still running fans due to wrong firmware.